# Firebase Realtime Database: Is there a way to avoid calling onDataChange when a value is removed?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid calling `onDataChange` when removing a value.
I want to remove all values inside a node but the node cannot be removed completely because I set this inside `onDataChange`.

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     if (!(dataSnapshot.haschild(aValue))
           //add aValue to the child

     if (dataSnapshot...
```

So the node is recreated immediately after the node is removed.
Also, the statement inside `onDataChange` is called even when the node is already removed so the app crashes.
Currently, I set `boolean` to check if the node is removed and it works but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid calling onDataChange when removing a value.

No, there is not. According to the official documentation regarding ValueEventListener's [onDataChange()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener.html#onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot)) method:

> This method will be called with a snapshot of the data at this location. It will also be called each time that data changes.

With other words, even if it is a write, an update or even a delete operation, this method is triggered. So everytime a change in your database takes place, `onDataChange()` fires and unfortunately you cannot avoid this.